# Calling variables within other variables in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a set of JSON templates in a CSV file and a DataInsert:
`{"Data":"${DataInsert}"}, testdatainsert`
Variables are defined as `JSONTemplate,DataInsert`

I'm running an HTTP request with the body:
`${__V(JSONTemplate${DataInsert})}`

And I would like this to send:
`{"Data":"testdatainsert"}`

However, what I end up sending is `JSONTemplatetestdatainsert`

I dont think I understood this documentation very well:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a value from CSV which holds another [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) - you need to wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) in order to resolve the underlying variable (or function).

If you have:

- `DataInsert` variable with the value of `testdatainsert`
- `JSONTemplate` variable with the value of `{"Data":"${DataInsert}"}`

and you need to get `{"Data":"testdatainsert"}` - you need to refer the variable as:

```
${__eval(${JSONTemplate})}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)